# How to limit a user to his / her folder?

Tags: 16.04, server, ssh, sftp

I want a user to access only its directory. So I have to add the following lines to /etc/ssh/sshd_config

```
Subsystem sftp internal-sftp
Match Group sftp
        ChrootDirectory /home/%u
        ForceCommand internal-sftp
        AllowTcpForwarding no
```

When I restart SSH :

```
service ssh restart
```

The following error is displayed :

```
Job for ssh.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status ssh.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

More details :

```
 ssh.service - OpenBSD Secure Shell server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/ssh.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2016-12-10 19:07:57 CET; 27s ago
  Process: 1928 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/sshd -D $SSHD_OPTS (code=exited, status=255)
 Main PID: 1928 (code=exited, status=255)

Dec 10 19:07:57 vps307796 systemd[1]: Starting OpenBSD Secure Shell server...
Dec 10 19:07:57 vps307796 sshd[1928]: /etc/ssh/sshd_config line 93: Directive 'UsePAM' is not allowed within
Dec 10 19:07:57 vps307796 systemd[1]: ssh.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=255/n/a
Dec 10 19:07:57 vps307796 systemd[1]: Failed to start OpenBSD Secure Shell server.
Dec 10 19:07:57 vps307796 systemd[1]: ssh.service: Unit entered failed state.
Dec 10 19:07:57 vps307796 systemd[1]: ssh.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

The response of "Jakuje" corrects the error. But I can not connect with a ftp client :

```
#  Allow client to pass locale environment variables
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*

Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server

# Set this to 'yes' to enable PAM authentication, account processing,
# and session processing. If this is enabled, PAM authentication will
# be allowed through the ChallengeResponseAuthentication and
# PasswordAuthentication.  Depending on your PAM configuration,
# PAM authentication via ChallengeResponseAuthentication may bypass
# the setting of "PermitRootLogin without-password".
# If you just want the PAM account and session checks to run without
# PAM authentication, then enable this but set PasswordAuthentication
# and ChallengeResponseAuthentication to 'no'.
UsePAM yes

        Match Group sftp
        ChrootDirectory /home/%u
        ForceCommand internal-sftp
        AllowTcpForwarding no
```

[image]

Comment: Now you are supposed to run the two commands mentioned in the error text: "systemctl status ssh.service" and "journalctl -xe"  .. and, if they dont give you a clue about the problem, edit your question with the output of those commands.

Comment: @Soren A I start with my server. I have updated the question.

Comment: It says that there is an error lin line 93 of /etc/ssh/sshd_config. Coul that relate to your newly added lines ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
...: /etc/ssh/sshd_config line 93: Directive 'UsePAM' is not allowed within
```

... match block.

You wrote the snippet of the configuration some place before the line 93 and therefore the `UsePam` option felt into this block too. Move your created snippet (`Match Group ...`) to the end of file and you shuold be good.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But I encounter another mistake. I have updated the question

Comment: Well, that is different thing to discuss, but having a look into the error log is again a good start before filling a new question.